# Best way to return recently created object in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm creating an object that when called it will create an database record and I want this function to return the newly created object. This is what I got:

```
data = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}

Dummy.new(data).save! # true
Dummy.last # newest record in the database
```

I'm concerned about what this would mean when there are more than one sessions on the same database. Is there a sure-fire way of getting the record I just created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just assign the instance you created to a variable:

```
data = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }

dummy = Dummy.new(data)
dummy.save!
dummy # the record you just created
```

Or use `create!` instead of `new` and `save!` like this:

```
data = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }

Dummy.create!(data) # returns the created instance or raises an error if not successful
```

Comment: I take it. Using `create!` did exactly what I wanted.